# Create a Model for Dummy Variables

Tags: python, r, dummy-variable

Starting with a training data set for a variable `var1` as:

```
var1
A
B
C
D
```

I want to create a model (let's call it `dummy_model1`) that would then transform the training data set to:

```
var1_A  var1_B  var1_C  var1_D
1       0       0       0
0       1       0       0
0       0       1       0
0       0       0       1
```

This functionality (or similar) exists in, among others, the `dummies` package in `R` and `get_dummies` in `Pandas`, or even `case` statements in `SQL`.

I'd like to then be able to apply `dummy_model1` to a new data set:

```
var1
C
7
#
A
```

and get the following output:

```
var1_A  var1_B  var1_C  var1_D
0       0       1       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
1       0       0       0
```

I know I can do this in `SQL` with 'case' statements but would love to automate the process given I have ~2,000 variables. Also, the new data sets will almost always have "bad" data (e.g., `7` and `#` in the above example).

Somewhat language agnostic (as long as its open source) but would prefer `Python` or `R`. Please note the data is over 500GB so that limits some of my options. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you asking?  SO is generally for specific programming questions, but you've presented no coding attempt -- just a problem description.

Comment: Right, but I don't know of a program/package that can do this so how can I ask a specific coding question?

Comment: You find a package or research the programming paradigm; both of those are outside the range of SO.  As presented, it appears that you're asking someone to design or write code for you.

Comment: In R, you could start by learning about the `model.matrix` function.

Comment: I'm also unclear how this requires a *model*, rather than a list of variable strings that you search for index position.

Comment: @Prune because each variable has between 10 and 200 levels and the documentation is less than perfect so I don't know what's in the variable unless I go through each variable 1 by 1. Figured I can't be the 1st to encounter this.

Comment: @joel.wilson added comment below. thanks.

Comment: Are you essentially asking how to transform your new data consistent with the dummy variable encoding you created (perhaps from `get_dummies`) from the training data? So the A and C get encoded by the 7 and # get ignored? If yes, I will post a brief Python answer.

Comment: Yes @NickBecker given the potential issues of file size (500GB+) and "bad data" in new data sets.

Comment: @NickBecker yes, that's exactly it, and thank you very much!

Comment: If by "bad" data you mean "different" data as opposed to "code breaking" data, that's not an issue. I'm assuming your 500gb dataset doesn't fit into memory (correct me if it does). If it doesn't, do a back of the envelope calculation (or just check) if your single column `var1` fits into memory.

Comment: @NickBecker a) generally different data but given the data comes from the "field" it could also literally be anything. b) the entire data set doesn't (or takes so long to import I've given up). I can get var1 to fit for most if not all variables.

Comment: @FrankB. Thanks; I have a somewhat better picture now.  I'll leave the solutions to those who are already writing them.

Comment: Gotcha. Then I'm going to write my solution assuming `var1` fits into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `var1` fits in memory on its own, here is a possible solution:

First, read in `var1`.

Next, use `get_dummies` to get all the "training" categories encoded as dummy variables. Store the column names as a list or an array.

Then, read in the first few rows of your training dataset to get the column names and store them as a list (or if you know these already you can skip this step).

Create a new list or array containing the dummy variable column names and the relevant other columns (this could just be every column in the dataset except `var1`). This will be the final columns encoding.

Then, read in your test data. Use `get_dummies` to encode `var1` in your test data, knowing it may be missing categories or have extraneous categories. Then reindex the data to match the final columns encoding.

After reindexing, you will end up a test dataset with `var1` dummies consistent with your training `var1`.

To illustrate:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

training = pd.DataFrame({
        'var1': ['a','b','c'],
        'other_var':[4,7,3],
        'yet_another':[8,0,2]
    })

print training
   other_var var1  yet_another
0          4    a            8
1          7    b            0
2          3    c            2

test = pd.DataFrame({
        'var1': ['a','b','q'],
        'other_var':[9,4,2],
        'yet_another':[9,1,5]
    })

print test
   other_var var1  yet_another
0          9    a            9
1          4    b            1
2          2    q            5


var1_dummied = pd.get_dummies(training.var1, prefix='var1')
var_dummy_columns =  var1_dummied.columns.values

print var_dummy_columns
array(['var1_a', 'var1_b', 'var1_c'], dtype=object)

final_encoding_columns = np.append(training.drop(['var1'], axis = 1).columns, var_dummy_columns)

print final_encoding_columns
array(['other_var', 'yet_another', 'var1_a', 'var1_b', 'var1_c'], dtype=object)


test_encoded = pd.get_dummies(test, columns=['var1'])

print test_encoded
   other_var  yet_another  var1_a  var1_b  var1_q
0          9            9       1       0       0
1          4            1       0       1       0
2          2            5       0       0       1

test_encoded_reindexed = test_encoded.reindex(columns = final_encoding_columns, fill_value=0)

print test_encoded_reindexed
   other_var  yet_another  var1_a  var1_b  var1_c
0          9            9       1       0       0
1          4            1       0       1       0
2          2            5       0       0       0
```

This should be what you want, based on the expected output in your question and the comments.

If the test data easily fits in memory, you can easily extend this to multiple variables. Just save and then update `final_encoding_columns` iteratively for each training variable you want to encode. Then pass all of those columns to the `columns=` argument when reindexing the test data. Reindex with your complete `final_encoding_columns` and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks Nick, and apologies for having you write custom code. I was hoping that someone has already put this into a package but give your answer I guess they haven't.

Comment: No worries at all. This is actually something that comes up fairly often when I put a model into production that uses encoded categorical variables, so I had some skeleton code easily accessible.

Answer (score 1):

just a try:

```
# first set the variable to factor with levels specified
df$var1 <- factor(df$var1, levels = LETTERS[1:4])

model.matrix(data = df, ~var1-1)
#  var1A var1B var1C var1D
#1     0     0     1     0
#4     1     0     0     0
```

---

```
# or even 
sapply(LETTERS[1:4], function(x) as.numeric(x==df$var1))
#     A B C D
#[1,] 0 0 1 0
#[2,] 0 0 0 0
#[3,] 0 0 0 0
#[4,] 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: The 2 (possible) issues I see is the data size issue for this (importing a 500GB+ CSV) and that I don't know what's in each of the variables upfront (documentation is spotty).

Comment: Not necessarily without manually inspecting every variable. Even if I have documentation saying the only values are 'A', 'B', and 'C' its still likely it's actually 'X', 'Y', and 'Z'