# Memory Efficient Hot Encode Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

EDIT: Still looking for an answer which works when the two datasets have different columns!

I'm trying to hot encode a particular column in both datasets **equally**.  The column has different values in different datasets, so a simple hot encoding will lead to different columns. Intended result:

```
DATASET A                           
col1    col2    target                  
a        1        1                 
b        2        2                 
c        2        3                 
d        3        3                 

DATASET B                           
col1    col2    target                  
d         2      2                  
h         4      3                  
g         2      2                  
b         3      3                  

After encoding col 1:                           

New dataset A                           

col2    target  a   b   c   d   h   g
1          1    1   0   0   0   0   0
2          2    0   1   0   0   0   0
2          3    0   0   1   0   0   0
3          3    0   0   0   1   0   0

New dataset B                           

col2    target  a   b   c   d   h   g
2          2    0   0   0   1   0   0
4          3    0   0   0   0   1   0
2          2    0   0   0   0   0   1
3          3    0   1   0   0   0   0
```

The following implementation works, but is very memory inefficient and frequently crashes my computer due to MemoryErrors.

```
 def hot_encode_column_in_both_datasets(column_name,df,df2,sparse=True,drop_first = True):
        print("Hot encoding {} for both datasets".format(column_name))
        cols_in_df_but_not_in_df2 = set(df[column_name]).difference(set(df2[column_name]))
        cols_in_df2_but_not_in_df = set(df2[column_name]).difference(set(df[column_name]))

        dummy_df_to_concat_to_df = pd.DataFrame(0,index=df.index,columns = cols_in_df2_but_not_in_df)
        dummy_df_to_concat_to_df2 = pd.DataFrame(0,index=df2.index,columns = cols_in_df_but_not_in_df2)

        dummy_df_to_concat_to_df = dummy_df_to_concat_to_df.to_sparse()
        dummy_df_to_concat_to_df2 = dummy_df_to_concat_to_df2.to_sparse()

        encoded = pd.get_dummies(df[column_name],sparse=sparse)
        encoded = pd.concat([encoded,dummy_df_to_concat_to_df],axis = 1)
        encoded_2 = pd.get_dummies(df2[column_name],sparse=sparse)
        encoded_2 = pd.concat([encoded_2,dummy_df_to_concat_to_df2],axis = 1)

        encoded_df = pd.concat([df,encoded],axis=1)
        encoded_df2 = pd.concat([df2,encoded_2],axis=1)

        del encoded_df[column_name]
        del encoded_df2[column_name]

        return encoded_df,encoded_df2
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you! :)

Comment: please don't put data or code as images. doing so discourages people who would like to help because they would have to type out the example data by hand.

Comment: @HaleemurAli Apologies, I thought it made it look cleaner. I'll fix it now! :)

Comment: From your example, it looks like you could just append your datasets, one hot encode, and then separate after the fact based on indices or a flag variable. Is there any reason this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the column you wish to encode a `Category` type column and take advantage of the fact that pandas methods, including the `get_dummies` method, respect that such columns may have values that are not observed in any particular DataFrame. This allows you to avoid any merge/join of the two DataFrames and makes the approach agnostic with respect to whether there are any columns that appear in one DataFrame but not both. Docs for [Categorical columns](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html).

I am using pandas v0.20.1.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string

dfa = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'col1': np.random.choice([ltr for ltr in string.ascii_lowercase[:4]], 5)
    , 'col2b': np.random.choice([1, 2, 3], 5)
    , 'target': np.random.choice([1, 2, 3], 5)
    })

dfb = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'col1': np.random.choice([ltr for ltr in string.ascii_lowercase[2:8]], 7)
    , 'col2b': np.random.choice(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 7)
    , 'target': np.random.choice([1, 2, 3], 7)
    })
```

dfa:

```
  col1  col2b  target
0    b      3       1
1    d      3       3
2    b      3       3
3    a      2       3
4    c      1       3
```

dfb:

```
  col1 col2b  target
0    g   foo       2
1    c   bar       1
2    h   baz       3
3    c   baz       3
4    d   baz       3
5    d   bar       2
6    d   foo       3
```

Find the union of the values of `col1` observed in the two DataFrames:

```
col1b = set(dfb.col1.unique())
col1a = set(dfa.col1.unique())
combined_cats = list(col1a.union(col1b))
```

Define the allowable values of `col1` identically on both DataFrames:

```
# Use these statements if `col1` is a 'Category' dtype.
# dfa['col1'] = dfa.col1.cat.set_categories(combined_cats)
# dfb['col1'] = dfb.col1.cat.set_categories(combined_cats)
# Otherwise, use these statements.
dfa['col1'] = dfa.col1.astype('category', categories=combined_cats)
dfb['col1'] = dfb.col1.astype('category', categories=combined_cats)

newdfa = pd.get_dummies(dfa, columns=['col1'])
newdfb = pd.get_dummies(dfb, columns=['col1'])
```

newdfa:

```
   col2b  target  col1_g  col1_b  col1_c  col1_d  col1_h  col1_a
0      3       1       0       1       0       0       0       0
1      3       3       0       0       0       1       0       0
2      3       3       0       1       0       0       0       0
3      2       3       0       0       0       0       0       1
4      1       3       0       0       1       0       0       0
```

newdfb:

```
  col2b  target  col1_g  col1_b  col1_c  col1_d  col1_h  col1_a
0   foo       2       1       0       0       0       0       0
1   bar       1       0       0       1       0       0       0
2   baz       3       0       0       0       0       1       0
3   baz       3       0       0       1       0       0       0
4   baz       3       0       0       0       1       0       0
5   bar       2       0       0       0       1       0       0
6   foo       3       0       0       0       1       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, this can be done by simply appending the dataframes before one hot encoding.

```
combined = a.append(b).reset_index(drop=True)
combinedDummies = pd.get_dummies(combined, columns=['col1'])

newA = combinedDummies.iloc[0:a.shape[0]]
newB = combinedDummies.iloc[a.shape[0]:]

newA
#   col2    target  col1_a  col1_b  col1_c  col1_d  col1_g  col1_h
#   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
#   1   2   2   0   1   0   0   0   0
#   2   2   3   0   0   1   0   0   0
#   3   3   3   0   0   0   1   0   0


newB
#   col2    target  col1_a  col1_b  col1_c  col1_d  col1_g  col1_h
#   4   2   2   0   0   0   1   0   0
#   5   4   3   0   0   0   0   0   1
#   6   2   2   0   0   0   0   1   0
#   7   3   3   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Hey i just realized, this doesnt work if the two datasets have some different columns

Comment: Right. Conceptually though, you don't need all the columns to create the dummy variables. You could just append the two relevant columns from each dataset and don't drop the index. I'd include a flag variable indicating which dataset it belongs to. Then you could just merge in the other variables after the fact based on the flag and indices.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create the "master" encoding and then reindex each dataframe separately before merging. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492300/create-a-model-for-dummy-variables

Comment: You mean only append the column in question?